# how to change the color of underline of TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

how do I change the color of underline of TextInputLayout?

I have tried to set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated, colorControlHighLight in themes but it does not work.

I want to set the color of underline white instead of black:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**please apply a custom theme in your text input layout**

example

```
    <style name="MYAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

use backgroundTint .

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

To change bottom line color, you can try this in your app Theme like below:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorControlNormal">#fffff</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#fffff</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#fffff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a style for that where I override

```
 <style name="FormLabel"> 
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

and I set this style to the `EditText` wrapped around the `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this my friend**

```
<style name="MYAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```